# Angular 2 prevent router navigation on child component click

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular-event-emitter

I have a template

```
<div (click)="handler()">
  <input type='checkbox' (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" (change)="$event.stopPropagation()">
</div>
```

and in my component here is the handler

```
handler() {
  this.router.navigate('path');
}
```

I wanted do nothing on checkbox click but to route on div click.

The above solution is not working.

Comment: Could you please give me more details for example, do you want when checkbox to be clicked? what should happen when user click on text? should it redirect?

Comment: The checkbox is a child element of the div. Clicking div means clicking anything inside the div element including child elements. More info as to what you want to achieve is needed.

Comment: But why would you need this? Could you please add more detail to your question?

Comment: @BasheerKharoti I have a common item component which has a checkbox and a  text element along side it. So I wrap each list components inside a div and I wanted to stop the child checkbox not to propagate on the parent div click

Comment: can you reproduce this?

Comment: Actually your code is working. i just tested it. If you have label for the checkbox,clicking on checkbox navigate to the path. also navigate method required a array like this  `this.router.navigate(['path])`

Answer (score 0):

First argument of navigate function has to be an array

```
this.router.navigate(['path']);
```

**OR**

you can use **navigateByUrl**,

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('path');
```

Since you are using `$event.stopPropagation()` when you click on the checkbox, navigation won't happen but when you simply click on the div, you will be navigated to expected route.

Comment: You haven't understoond the question. He meant to `stop propagation` when clicked on checkbox

Comment: I do understand it but he is not using `checked or unchecked` value anywhere. It will stop event bubbling which is fine but there is no use of checkbox technically as per his code.

Comment: he might haven't showed the model binding though `(change)="$event.stopPropagation()"` is what he meant to stop bubbling

Answer (score 0):

This setup works for me:

```
<div (click)="onDivClick()">
  <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" (change)="onCheckboxChange($event)"></mat-checkbox>
</div>

...

onDivClick() {
  console.log('div clicked');
}

onCheckboxChange(event) {
  console.log(event);
}
```

Important to note:
`MatCheckboxChange` event type does not have a `stopPropagation()` function so your example code should actually display an error in the console.
So you want the `stopPropagation()` only on the checkbox click.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out I have a label that wraps the checkbox. So, I needed to add the click event to stop propagation at the label element